# Ajax dont return values in drupal 7

Tags: ajax, drupal-7

Im in drupal 7, i need to make a select with many options, depends of the option taken, in a textarea will be loaded several values in a string.

After hours of test i come here for help.

Im working on a basic page:

```
function ajax_load_all_admins($form, &$form_state) {
    $form = array();
    $form['changethis'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => array(
            '' => '',
            '1' => 'Cargar todos los admins'
        ),
        '#ajax' => array(
            'event' => 'change',
            'callback' => 'ajax_load_all_admins_callback',
            'wrapper' => 'listaCorreos-div'
        )
    );

    $form['listaCorreos'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#prefix' => '<div id="listaCorreos-div">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>'
    );

    if (!empty($form_state['values']['changethis'])) {
        $payments_list = db_query('QUERY WORKING WELL');  

        $value = '';
        foreach ($payments_list as $payment) {
            $value .= $payment->admin . ',';
        }
        trim($value, ',');
        $form['listaCorreos']['#default_value'] = $value;
    }

    return $form;
}

function ajax_load_all_admins_callback($form, $form_state) {
    return $form['listaCorreos'];
}

$form = drupal_get_form('ajax_load_all_admins');
print drupal_render($form);
```

The Ajax call is working but i only recibe:

```
0: {command:settings, settings:{basePath:/, pathPrefix:,…}, merge:true}
```

No other one position.

I think it can be for the drupal_render, but dont know why?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing this ajax functions in a simple view, created to make an specific form.

**I move all the logic to a new module, instead of simple view and now is working.**

I take a look to the ajax examples of "examples module" and test if they works on a simple view,like my code, dont works.

I think for any reason, drupal ajax only works if the render is not manually, like i was doing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

since the ajax itself works;
Looks to me like the db_query isn't working well and/or returning unexpected results.

My advice: You should be able to debug. i.e. setting a breakpoint and stepping into your code line by line
I do it with netbeans & XDEBUG

This should gives you a great edge solving this & upcoming similar problems, as you'll be able to monitor your variables & the execution tree of your code

Best of luck.

--edit-- This should be totally in the comment section, but ... new here , cant comment at the moment.. apologies.

Comment: I think maybe error was on: $form = drupal_get_form('ajax_load_all_admins');
print drupal_render($form);